# How to get the value from div class in selenium WebDriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me on this. I am new selenium and don't know how to select the value from a window  with the drop down value.

Pleas help me how to write the below value in selenium:

```
<div class="inmplayer-list-item inmplayer-list-item-topic-47634 inmplayer-list-
item-folder inmplayer-folder-turn-up" title="">
<span class="inmplayer-folder-symbol"></span>Orientation</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can select a value from a dropdown using `Select` class with `selectByvalue` or `SelectByVisibleText` or `SelectByIndex` depending upon your need.
The following code is used for selecting a value from a dropdown.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElementById("specify your locator value");    
Select dropdown = new Select(element);    
dropdown.SelectByVisibleText("Your text value");
```